# Work with complex animations on Blaze

Tags: css, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, animate.css

I actually looking for a good way to play animations on my app context with **Blaze**.

To be more explicit, I wrote this super simple example:

```
<template name="global">
    <h1>Hi guys!</h1>
    {{> foo}}
</template>

<template name="foo">
    <h2>I'm a foo!</h2>
    <ul>
    {{#each elements}}
        {{> bar}}
    }}
    </ul>

    <button name="btnAdd">Add new elem</button>
    <button name="btnDel">Delete an elem</button>
</template>

<template name="bar">
    <li>{{name}}</li>
</template>
```

Let's assume we got an **Iron-router** route which render the `global` Template.
On this particular render (from "navigate") I want each templates to render with `fadeIn`.

When click on `btnAdd` button, a new element created. I wish it would render with `SlideInLeft` effect.

When click on `btnDel` button, an element is deleted. I wish it would be destroyed with `SlideOutRight` effect.

When user navigate to another route, I want all template disappear with `fadeOut` effect.

Every of my attempt so far wouldn't allow me to do this kind of distinction... I couldn't find any package resolving this problem neither.

I'm actually just playing animation by adding/removing **Animate.css** class (pretty simple to use and good looking!)

To resume, I want a different animation played depending on the source of the rendering.

Does someone had already face this problem?

**BONUS QUESTION:** Do you know how to chain animations, like:

render global with fadeIn Effect >> then >> render foo with rotateIn Effect >> then >> render every bar with bounceIn effect

Comment: Did you already see this? https://github.com/webtempest/meteor-animate

Comment: @Kalman: Yes, that do not solve the problem, it's does not allow to choose animation on different context, it will just be played each time binded element is rendered

Answer (score 2):

For timing, you can use `Meteor.setInterval`. For example, you can do `$('.elementClass').hide('fast')` outside `setInterval`. It will run first and `setInterval` will run when you want it to.

For the initial effects, you can use:

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function(){
    $('.elementClass').fadeIn('fast') //note that element is initially hidden (display:none in CSS). you can use effects from jquery and jquery-ui for more effects. You have to add jquery-ui additionally
})
```

You can also use jQuery in your router.js, using iron:router.

```
Router.route('/the-url', function() {
    this.render('templateName', {
        data: function () {
            $('.htmlElement').toggle('slide', {direction:'right'}, 200); //note that the element is initially invisible
        }
    });
}, {
     name: 'routeName'
});
```

Comment: Yep that answer to the bonus question (I knew I could do it with setInterval, but maybe it was possible to do it on other way ;) ). Anyway thanks, but that does not solve the main problem...

Comment: @JulienLeray I think it does. You can just add any effect you want to any element with onRendered or you can use jQuery in your route. Additionally, you can do any effect you want with events. For example, you click, it does the effect you want, then removes your document.

Comment: Let me know if you don't know how to write it and I'll edit my question.

Comment: I still don't know how you can handle different animation on Rendering depending on a page change or a new element added. Same for delete, where and how play an animation on item delete different than the page change?

Comment: When the page changes, you have different templates that renders which triggers onRendered(). when a template is rendered, you can easily add effects with jQuery to show any effect for an HTLM element when the page/template is rendered. For the delete, in your template events, you can do 1: do the effect, 2: Meteor.call('deleteSomething').

Comment: @JulienLeray I just edited my answer with more details

Comment: Thanks I will try that and tell you how it goes! How can you do the same for the onDestroyed?

Comment: @JulienLeray You can't show an effect then destroy/remove something using onDestroyed() because it gets called when the template is destroyed. What you want to do is showing an effect, then destroying which you can do in an event. Edit your question with your new codes if you can't make it work. PS: if any of the answers provide something useful to any of your questions, give an upvote (: Cheers!